Error occurred during update: ORA-01403: no data found when using update in forall in stored procedure in Oracle
Below is the stored procedure I have created. It is the "Create" stored procedure. I am getting error while updating the data.
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_STATUS IS

TYPE employee_info_rec IS RECORD(
        id employee.id%type,
        name employee.name%type
    );
TYPE employee_info_table IS TABLE OF employee_info_rec INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

employee_info_data employee_info_table;    
CURSOR emp_details is
    SELECT AA.id, AA.name from employee AA;
          
    l_limit PLS_INTEGER := 10000;
    i PLS_INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    OPEN emp_details;
    LOOP 
        FETCH emp_details BULK COLLECT INTO employee_info_data LIMIT l_limit;
        EXIT WHEN employee_info_data.COUNT = 0;
        BEGIN
        FORALL i IN 1 .. employee_info_data.COUNT                    
            UPDATE employee
            SET emp_status = 1
            WHERE id = employee_info_data(i).id;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Processed id: ' || employee_info_data(i).id || ', name: ' || employee_info_data(i).name);
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error occurred during update: ' || SQLERRM);
            ROLLBACK;
        END;
        
    END LOOP;
    
    COMMIT;
    CLOSE emp_details;
END UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_STATUS;
/
execute UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_STATUS;

I have the related data in table but I am getting the error shown here. Can you please go through the SQL query and let me know why I am getting this error?

Error occurred during update: ORA-01403: no data found

Records should be updated with print statement like
Expected output:
Processed id: 1, Name: Manoj
....


Your procedure won't compile, because you're referring to establishment_org, which isn't part of your record type. If that is changed to id then it compiles and executes, and gets the error you showed.
If you remove the exception handler you can see the full error stack, which points to the line that is erroring. That is not the update statement. Apart from anything else, an update won't throw that, it would just silently update zero rows if there was no matching data.
The error is coming from the following dbms_output line. You are doing:
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Processed id: ' || employee_info_data(i).id || ', name: ' || employee_info_data(i).name);

but this it not part of the forall statement, so it's using the previously declared variable i which still has value 0. There is no element in the collection with index 0, so you get that error. (Admittedly it's a bit confusing to use the same error you'd get from a query against a table.)
The i in FORALL i IN ... is a completely independent variable that is only in scope for that statement - you don't need to declare your own i and it is only causing confusion.
fiddle with the exception handler, local i variable and dbms_output commented out to show it works.
It's using the id field from the record, so it may not be doing what you want or intended - effectively this is just a long-winded and slower way of doing update employee set emp_status = 1, at least if id can't be null.
(The exception handler is odd anyway - if it errored in the second batch of 10000 rows it would rollback everything it had updated already; but would then carry on updating the next batch and eventually commit those, leaving you in a weird state. In general you shouldn't commit or rollback in a procedure anyway - let the caller decide to commit or rollback the entire call. And letting the exception propagate instead of catching it, especially with when others, would let the caller know it had gone wrong.)

As shown in the documentation, the forall statement includes a single DML statement, which is the update here. If you really need to have a message output for every row as you update it then you will need to use a normal for loop, which loses the bulk-processing benefits of forall, but you can have both the update and dbms_output call within that loop.
Also as the update won't error if there is no matching row, you can check sql%rowcount to see if an update actually occurred, and display your message as appropriate if you want (and if your real update might not find a match).
You can also keep the forall and have a separate loop afterwards to just display a message for every element in the collection. But that won't tell if any of those found no matching row to actually update, if that can happen.
